# Providing path to Firefox/Chrome/IE installation in cygwin

Tags: selenium, cygwin, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver, selenium-grid2

I'm trying to launch Firefox remotely on a windows machine from UNIX box using `remotewebdriver`.

I've tried by adding Firefox in the PATH as below:

```
$ echo $PATH
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/
```

But still the browser fails to launch as the `geckodriver.exe` tries to find Firefox in the windows default path.

Here is the log from selenium hub:

> 1486475449767   mozprofile::profile     INFO    Using profile path
>   C:\cygwin64\tmp\rus
>   t_mozprofile.Rmyr2i85U1HV
>
> 1486475449774   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser 
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe

I also tried adding below property while launching selenium node:

> -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/"

However, the exception was thrown:

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 'webdriver.firefox.bin' property set, but unable to locate the requested binary: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/.exe
>   
> .....
> .....
>   Exception: Could not initialize class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.Executable

Is there a way to provide the path to the firefox installation folder?

---

EDIT:

After providing parameters:

> -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver.exe -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="firefox/firefox.exe"

The execution gets stuck at:

> 1486534065121   mozprofile::profile     INFO    Using profile path C:\cygwin64\tmp\rust_mozprofile.eqdfIaNAGjDu
>   1486534065135   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser >C:\cygwin64\home\Administrator\firefox\firefox.exe
>
> 1486534065198   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:56702
>
> 1486534068740   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 56702

Answer (score 0):

Try escape characters and specify the .exe file:

`-Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="/cygdrive/c/Program Files\ (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"`

Comment: Tried installing firefox in /home/Administrator/firefox and passed below args to the grid
-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver.exe -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="firefox/firefox.exe"

The execution got stuck right before launching the browser

Comment: I've added a new questiopn [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106180/selenium-remotewebdriver-stuckbefore-launching-browser) with new issue