# Selenium remotewebdriver stuck before launching browser

Tags: selenium, cygwin, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver, selenium-grid2

I'm trying to launch Firefox remotely on a windows machine from UNIX box using remotewebdriver
 I am also starting the selenium node remotely using ssh(It starts fine) using Cygwin and OpenSSH.
(I've installed firefox in the path c:\cygwin64\home\Administrator\firefox)

I am launching the grid node using:

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role node -hub http://HUB_IP:4444/grid/register -port 5566 -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver.exe -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="firefox/firefox.exe"

However, the execution gets stcuk at:

> 1486534648695   mozprofile::profile     INFO    Using profile path C:\cygwin64\tmp\rust_mozprofile.lpsQghom5pxe
>   1486534648699   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\cygwin64\home\Administrator\firefox\firefox.exe
>   1486534648719   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:57059
>   1486534650177   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 57059

I can see the firefox process starts but browser does not launch and gets stuck.
(Tried the same for chrome, getting the same issue)
After waiting for a long time, node throws exception:,

> A coding exception was thrown and uncaught in a Task.
>   Full message: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
>   Full stack:

EDIT:
I cannot launch Firefox/Chrome from Cygwin when I manually go to the installation path and give the command firefox.exe. This gets stuck as well but a process is started. This occurs only when I use a remote connection. Though, using Cygwin locally launches the browsers.  
Is there a way to enable this?

Comment: You must be sure that hub can reach node, and vice versa. It may be a network issue like subnet or dns

Comment: Hub and nodes are able to communicate with each other. Can see the node in the Hub UI and in logs.

Comment: There are some normal things here. 
`Marionette INFO Listening on port 57059` actually means that the driver is listening and waiting some commands to execute on the browser. And concerning the process launched but no GUI, it's normal too because cygwin uses the system user and has no access to the display and then, you cannot see Firefox on screen

Comment: When does the NetworkError happens ? When you launch the jar on node mode ? Or when you send commands to the node ?

Comment: The issue is not just the UI displaying, I cannot even do a driver.maximize() or get a URL. The execution seems to get stuck.